# How to add a specific number of Field Collection items drived by a textbox with OnChange event?

Tags: ajax, entities

Here is a FieldCollection of "FirstName, LastName"

[image]

As you can see, there is a Textbox "Spaces" and under that a tables which is comming from my Field Collection. Right now if I want to add a combination of "Firstname / LastName" I need to click on Add another Item button. I want to remove that button and controle the numbers of items with the "Spaces" textbox. If I put 4 in the "Spaces" textbox, 4 rows should appear in the Guest List.

How can I do that?

Comment: Far as I know there is not  module for this, you must program this behavior.